# Why does my Visual Studio Terminal print directories and links?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am a beginner and I can't seem to clean up my terminal. Every time I run code, Visual Studio prints it in its terminal and more than the code appears. How do I remove everything but the code? A simple Hello World code outputs this:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Ex_Files_Learning_Python> & C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Ex_Files_Learning_Python/Exercise Files/Ch2/Untitled-1.py"
hello world!
PS C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Ex_Files_Learning_Python>
```

Comment: What precisely did you want to remove?  Part of the command prompt too?

Comment: If you want to shorten/modify the command prompt (in your case `PS C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Ex_Files_Learning_Python>`) see PS C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Ex_Files_Learning_Python>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't avoid this. Your code is being executed in the terminal and that is what it takes to pass the script to Python to run it.